# For loop to add empty rows to datatable isn't working

Tags: c#, for-loop, datatable, datarow

I have some code to compare two DataTables. If one table has more rows than the other, I want to be able to add blank rows until they have an equal row count.

I have tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++)
{
    table.Rows.Add();
}
```

as well as

```
DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
table.ImportRow(newRow);
```

and

```
DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
table.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

None of these seem to work.

table.Rows.Add() (with and without the param) seems to break me out of the loop after one iteration

ImportRow loops around the appropriate amount of times, but only adds one new row

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the schema / layout of the table you are adding to?

Comment: what is the value of difference?

Comment: Do you create a new DataRow object with each iteration of the loop - regarding your second attempt?

Comment: @inquisitive_mind a positive integer that changes depending on the tables being used eg 5

Comment: @DanOrlovsky yes, it looked just like James Dev's answer (but with 'difference' instead of 5

Comment: We may need to see more code.  There's gotta be something else going on.  @Pikoh does have a good line of questions in their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works ok to me:

```
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
dtable.Columns.Add("Column1");
dtable.Columns.Add("Column2");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
      DataRow newRow = dtable.NewRow();
      dtable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

It,as expected, adds 10 empty rows to my DataTable. If this doesn't work to you, maybe your DataTable has a primary key or other restriction that prevents to add those empty rows. Show us your DataTable definition in that case.

**Edit**

In this example based on the previous I define a primary key, so this code doesn't work:

```
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
dtable.Columns.Add("Key");
dtable.Columns.Add("Column2");
dtable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]{dtable.Columns[0]};

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    DataRow newRow = dtable.NewRow();
    dtable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

It fails with a `NoNullAllowedException`, this is, the Primary Key can't be null.

The following code works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    DataRow newRow = dtable.NewRow();
    newRow["Key"] = i;
    dtable.Rows.Add(newRow);

}
```

Because I'm setting a value to the Primary Key. In your case, it depends of the DataType of your PrimaryKey, and you must check also if the values you are "inventing" are already present or it will also fail.

I hope this is clear now for you.

Comment: I have tried this code, so I think you must be right about the primary key. Will that mean I'll set to set the primary key of these new rows before I add them?

Comment: Yes @Sophia , if the datatable has any primary key,you should set that column in the new rows, because primary keys must be unique and if all the rows are empty they would have the same primary key.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure how to do this.. More information would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @Sophia see my updated answer and see if you understand everything. We cannot help you more without seeing your DataTable definition. Anyway, what you are trying is a bit strange, why do you want to have the two tables with the same number of rows? Maybe if you explain why we could give you an alternative solution

Comment: It is a WinForm that compares two datatables and highlights the differences between them :) and YAAAAY your new code worked, thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

With this test:

```
        var table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

The DataTable table contains 5 rows.